# Double.Parse on a german system result in comma instead of decimal point

Tags: c#, globalization

I have the following:

```
 private static string someValue = "0.1";
```

I need to convert this into double in order to do some calculation.
On a German system I get the conversion as 0,1 rather than 0.1, I need it as 0.1.
I tried the following:

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(s_valueDeadband10Percent, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat); // still getting 0,1
```

AND

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(s_valueDeadband10Percent, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // still getting 0,1
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you convert `s_valueDeadband10Percent` when the field is actually `someValue`? Your title also shows `Double.Parse` and your code `Convert.ToDouble`. Please be more thorough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> On a German system I get the conversion as 0,1 rather than 0.1, I need it as 0.1.

No, you don't get either of those. You get a `double` value which is approximately a tenth. A `double` value isn't a textual "thing" at all. It can be *converted* to text, but that's a different operation. You need to find where that operation is, and change *that* to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, if you really want a text value. But if you can get away without the conversion back to a string at all, that would be even better.

Of course, if possible, you should change your static variable to be a `double` to start with:

```
private static double someValue = 0.1;
```

That way you can avoid parsing, too.

Comment: It's also seems to be a debugger/visual studio display-issue  since OP converts a string to double and he complains that the double shows `0,1` instead of `0.1`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, that's what I meant by "It can be converted to text, but that's a different operation. You need to find where that operation is, and change that to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, if you really want a text value." We don't know *where* the OP is converting the value back to text.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the string representation of your double with the actual value.

Your code should convert the string "0.1" nicely to 0.1d. Whenever you print it (in the debugger, on the console or on a webpage), it needs to be converted back to a string, which might happen implicitly in your case. The double is just some floating point bits that in itself has no definition of it's printed representation.

If the conversion from double to string is done in the german culture, you will see "0,1".

Try printing this

```
d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```